# Widgets do not place in desired position - Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, position

I have a weird problem with Tkinter. So I have a `1000x1000` window, and I have a few labels placed around the window. The labels were placed by the user with a drag and drop function, and each label was dynamically created using a dictionary. After the positioning is done, when a label is clicked, the function below is called (through the method `bind`, and each label was accessed through the dictionary).

```
def moveNattack(event):
    Ycord =  window.winfo_pointery()
    Xcord = window.winfo_pointerx()
    print(Xcord, Ycord)
    ex = tk.Label(window, text = 'X', relief = 'raised', background = 'firebrick3', width = 2, height = 1)
    if Ycord < 500:
        ex.place_forget()
        ex.place(x = Xcord, y = Ycord + 20)
```

What I am trying to do is create another label with "X" as its text called `ex`. If the label is clicked above the 500 pixel mark, I want `ex` to be placed 20 pixels below the clicked label.

So the problem I am having is that for some random reason `ex` is being placed around 10 - 100 pixels to the right even though the coordinates in the function above are supposed to place `ex` below the clicked label. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, here is the dictionary, in which the `list(range(...))` command created the variables to be assigned to the labels in another function.

```
troops = {
    'playerOne' : {
        'gunner' : list(range(4)),
        'rifle' : list(range(6)),
        'rocket' : list(range(2)),
        'machinegun' : list(range(4)),
        'tank' : list(range(3))
    },
    'playerTwo' : {
        'gunner' : list(range(4)),
        'rifle' : list(range(6)),
        'rocket' : list(range(2)),
        'machinegun' : list(range(4)),
        'tank' : list(range(3))
    }
}
```

And this is a picture of my problem:
[image]

Please comment if you have questions.

Comment: I seriously doubt `winfo_pointerx` is returning the wrong information. Are you aware it reports in units relative to the screen as a whole, not just the window? Using the root window coordinates is rarely useful.

Comment: You're probably not going to get much help unless you create a [mcve]. Your description isn't enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I found out how to fix it. I'm new to using `winfo`, so I didn't know how to fix it before.

Comment: If you have the answer to your own question and think it can be useful for other people with the same problem, please don't put it in the question, but post an actual answer. That way the question remains the way it was and everybody can see that it is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time guys, but I just figured out that you need to subtract the mouse positions from the root positions. `winfo_pointerx` and `winfo_pointery` both return coordinates relative to the whole computer screen, and to get the coordinates in the program's window you need to subtract `winfo_rootx` and `winfo_rooty` from it. Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem.